# how to type right } in lstinline

Tags: latex, lstlisting

how to type right } in lstinline.
I cannot insert

```
\lstinline{{}}
```

The left{ is work well, but the right cause error.

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some other character, which does not occur in your listing, to delimit the lstinline argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstinline|{}|

\lstinline@{}@

\lstinline!{}!

\lstinline*{}*

\end{document}
```